# Which update to install in nexus 7 4.3 manually?

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-7

I got new nexus 7 2013   edition wifi with 32 gb   razor  flo with 4.3  . Automatic system update is showing updating  to 4.4.2 and its very slow stick at 253.2 mb  . I want to know which update can i install manually via adb , I downloaded 5.0.1 image can i install this directly from 4.3  or  which update do i install in my device of updates available here :
https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images
which image do i download and install . i think direct 4.3 to 5.0.1  is not posssible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this question would be better asked on the [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) site I will answer it - in the future please ask non development related questions on that site.

You can absolutely flash those images directly to your device. They are system images and contain the full code for the matching version. You can upgrade or downgrade using those images without problem - it is in fact exactly what they are intended for.

The procedure to update is listed under **Flashing Instructions** at the [link you specified](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) in your question, so follow that exactly and you should be fine (it's quite simple). Just be aware that flashing a system image will **remove all user data**!